# Mean squared displacement

Tags: python, random-walk

I am investigating the motion of a single micrometer sized particle in a low density plasma. With a so called long distance microscope I have recorded the motion of a particle (2726 images, fps=60 Hz).

The x,y data in mm are available here: http://pastebin.com/qdMsaUHD

With mathematica I got the following log-log plot for the mean squared displacement (MSD):

[image]

**I am new to Python and have searched for examples on how to read in the 2D coordinates from a file, calculate and display the MSD (mean and standard deviation).**

I have seen that there are some answers which show how to calculate the MSD but I am not able to adapt them to my data.

I would appreciate very much if somebody could show me the full Python source code (with all imports) which is necessary to solve my problem.

That will be for me a great opportunity and a very concrete problem to start also programming with Python. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

I tried the following from one of the answers ([Computing the mean square displacement of a 2d random walk in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472653/computing-the-mean-square-displacement-of-a-2d-random-walk-in-python/27709260#comment60361901_27709260)), but the code produced errors.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data= [[49.136926889715, 48.4423791821561],
[48.8104534783146, 51.0491783022365],
[48.5231487166892, 53.3485202014],
[48.2320069851565, 55.2569539728078],
[47.8817794028032, 56.993296770262],
[47.381875792142, 58.179721166033],
...
[45.3409434914228, 49.0259838546922]]

def compute_MSD(path):
   totalsize=len(path)
   msd=[]
   for i in range(totalsize-1):
       j=i+1
       msd.append(np.sum((path[0:-j]-path[j::])**2)/float(totalsize-j))

   msd=np.array(msd)
   return msd

result=compute_MSD(data)

plt.plot(result)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Have you read the data into python list ?

Answer (score 2):

My graphs look slightly different than yours which likely stems from a misunderstanding of exactly what it is you are calculating, however I believe this addresses the basic idea.

```
plasma = [[0.09296720430107527, 0.09280376344086022],
[0.09230113636363636, 0.09769886363636364],
[0.09130555555555556, 0.10198777777777777],
...

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(plasma, columns=['x', 'y'])
df['time'] = np.arange(0,len(df)) / 60.0
df['dist'] = np.sqrt(df['x']**2 + df['y']**2)
df['MSD'] = pd.rolling_mean((np.abs(df['dist'])**2), len(df), min_periods=1)
```

The above is my interpretation of what you mean by MSD. I am using distance from the origin, i.e. `sqrt(x^2 + y^2)` and then applying the following [definition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanSquareDisplacement.html)

Then you can create a plot using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) as follows

```
plt.loglog(df['time'], df['MSD'], 'o')
plt.xlabel('t (sec)')
plt.ylabel('MSD')
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to touch up / refine the graphs an excellent place to get a handle on matplotlib is the tutorial section, [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you very much ... I have to check why your  y values are different and also the curve variation looks different ... it can also be that I made a mistake ... but it helps me

Comment: I was also unclear what colour in your plot above represented

Answer (score 0):

Numpy has a standard function to calculate standard deviation. You can use `numpy.std` function. Give the list as input and it would output the result. You don't need to write those loops to do it.

To get same result as MATLAB set `ddof = 1` in argument to `numpy.std` function.

Refer [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) for examples.

Comment: my question is mainly about the mean squared displacement ...